# How to compile and run an C executable in gem-5 that use text file as input and output in gem5 SE mode with se.py?

Tags: x86, processor, gem5

I have a C code that takes value form two input file calculate multiplication and write the time into another text file. First I compile and make executable with GCC and the name is Method1_X86_BINARY_

> gcc DecMulTimeMeasure.c decContext.c decDouble.c decQuad.c -o Method1_X86_BINARY_

The executable is working ./Method1_X86_BINARY_ file!
Now I want to compile using gem5 SE mode by bellow command

> ./build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py -c tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/Method1_X86_BINARY_

After that I receive following error

> GEM5 SIMULATION START problem reading inputA.txt file Exiting @ tick 9053500 because exiting with last active thread context
>   Simulated exit code not 0! Exit code is 1

The Message ***GEM5 SIMULATION START*** and ***problem reading inputA.txt file*** shows form my C code where bellow :

```
>FILE *ptr_file_read, *ptr_file_readB,*ptr_file_write , *Mptr_file_write;
 char fileNameA [40] = "final_result_a.txt";
 char fileNameB [40] = "final_result_b.txt";
 printf("GEM5 SIMULATION START");
ptr_file_read = fopen(fileNameA, "r"); //Name of the input file
if (!ptr_file_read)
{
     printf("problem reading inputA.txt file");
      return 1;
 }
```

So the message ***GEM5 SIMULATION START*** indicate that the executable is okay where as the message ***problem reading inputA.txt file*** indicates the problem is during reading form text file.

My question is how I can run the file in GEM-5 simulator.

Here I upload full project with little description in readme. github.com/riazcseiu/DecimalMultiplication.git

Comment: Print the error message using `perror` so you know what kind of error has occurred. Is the file `final_result_a.txt` in the same directory as `Method1_X86_BINARY_`?

Comment: I have tested with 08c79a194d1a3430801c04f37d13216cc9ec1da3 and a simple C program that writes and reads to a file, and the program worked exactly inside of gem5 and on my host. Does your program work on your host? Can you provide a minimal failing C program so that others can try to reproduce? Mailing list thread: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16597.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here I upload full project with little description in readme for you. https://github.com/riazcseiu/DecimalMultiplication.git

Answer (score 0):

General compile and run shown at: [How to compile and run an executable in gem5 syscall emulation mode with se.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085048/how-to-compile-and-run-an-executable-in-gem5-syscall-emulation-mode-with-se-py/53085049#53085049)

Then, I test it in gem5 211869ea950f3cc3116655f06b1d46d3fa39fb3a (October 2019), and opening and closing or regular files just works normally: files can be read from host, and written to host filesystem normally.

I have tested this with [this minimal C file write / read example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/5b7094fb68e36c2c4af73e8a209a979ebbf32eae/userland/c/file_write_read.c).

The file [src/doc/se-files.txt](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/211869ea950f3cc3116655f06b1d46d3fa39fb3a/src/doc/se-files.txt) documents the implementation of this feature.

I believe gem5 then treats some special Linux files e.g. under `/proc` and `/sys` specially since those require more complex interactions with the kernel that gem5 is simulating in SE.