# How "Hello World!" program is running in Gem5 by default. How i can run my sorting programs in Gem5?

Tags: gem5

I am new in gem5. I am not able to get which C program is printing "Hello World!" in gem5 by default. To run my own program where i have to save my file and how to compile and run it. I want to run my programs of sorting. How i can do it? I have read many posts and answers here but they are confusing and not helping to complete my task. Please Help!!!

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085048/how-to-compile-and-run-an-executable-in-gem5-syscall-emulation-mode-with-se-py/53085049#53085049 If it doesn't answer the question, could you clarify what you are trying to do more specifically? (reposted a new comment to correct wrong link on previous)